# Magento 2 - How to add dynamic-rows grid on catalog product

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, dynamic-rows

I am using Magento 2.1.5

I need to add a dynamic rows grid on the catalog product page

[image]

I am using the below di.xml for adding a dynamic row on product_form

> app/code/vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="Duration" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">[vendor]\[module]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Duration</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>

     <type name="[vendor]\[module]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Modifier\Duration">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="formName" xsi:type="string">product_form</argument>
            <argument name="dataScopeName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form</argument>
            <argument name="dataSourceName" xsi:type="string">product_form.product_form_data_source</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

My question is what can I do in the data provider to get these duration options?

Answer (score -1):

Add Form directory before Modifier 
[vendor][module]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Duration

and add this in the Duration File

```
    <?php
[vendor]\[module]\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Duration

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type as CatalogType;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierFactory;

class Duration extends AbstractModifier
{

const CHILDREN_PATH = '[your_system_path]/children';
const CONTAINER_FILES = 'container_files';

/**
 * @var ModifierFactory
 */
protected $modifierFactory;

/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $modifiers = [];

/**
 * @var ModifierInterface[]
 */
protected $modifiersInstances = [];

/**
 * @var LocatorInterface
 */
protected $locator;

/**
 * Composite constructor.
 * @param ModifierFactory $modifierFactory
 * @param LocatorInterface $locator
 * @param array $modifiers
 */
public function __construct(
    ModifierFactory $modifierFactory,
    LocatorInterface $locator,
    array $modifiers = []
) {
    $this->modifierFactory = $modifierFactory;
    $this->locator = $locator;
    $this->modifiers = $modifiers;
}

/**
 * @param array $data
 * @return array
 */
public function modifyData(array $data)
{
    foreach ($this->getModifiers() as $modifier) {
        $data = $modifier->modifyData($data);
    }

    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param array $meta
 * @return array
 */
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
    foreach ($this->getModifiers() as $modifier) {
        $meta = $modifier->modifyMeta($meta);
    }


    return $meta;
}


/**
 * @return \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\ModifierInterface[]
 */
protected function getModifiers()
{
    if (empty($this->modifiersInstances)) {
        foreach ($this->modifiers as $modifierClass) {
            $this->modifiersInstances[$modifierClass] = $this->modifierFactory->create($modifierClass);
        }
    }

    return $this->modifiersInstances;
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer with why and not just what.